# No se puede convertir de 'Android.Net.Uri' a 'string'

Tags: c#, xamarin

Estoy intentando guardar un imagen adjunta en una variable para enviar por correo pero me sale este error:

> No se puede convertir de 'Android.Net.Uri' a 'string'

Envío código donde me sale error:

```
if (uris != null)
{
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(uris, "");
    var File = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
    var path = Uri.FromFile(File);
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream, path));
}
```

Código completo:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    textView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Autorizaciones, container, false);
    textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoNombre).Text = mTxtNombre;
    textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAutoCedula).Text = mTxtCedula;
    imageView = textView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgMostrarFotos);

    Adjuntar = textView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCamara);
    Enviar = textView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnEnviar);
    Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

    Adjuntar.Click += delegate
    {
        var imageIntent = new Intent();
        imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
        imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), 0);
    };

    Enviar.Click += delegate 
    {
        try
        {
            string smtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
            int portNumber = 587;
            bool enableSSL = true;
            string emailFrom = "ingsisacontreras@gmail.com";
            string password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
            string emailTo = "ingsisacontreras@gmail.com";
            string subject = "Tramite Autorización "+ mTxtNombre;
            string body = "Hello, Mr."+mTxtCedula;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
            mail.To.Add(emailTo);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;


            if (uris != null)
            {
                var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(uris, "");
                var File = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                var path = Uri.FromFile(File);
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream, path));
            }


            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
            {
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                smtp.Send(mail);
            }

            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Mensaje Enviado" , ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Mensaje Fallido" +ex, ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    };

    return textView;

}

public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        imageView = textView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImgMostrarFotos);
        imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);
        imageView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        uris = GetPathToImage(data.Data);
        Enviar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
}

private string GetPathToImage(Uri uri )
{
    string doc_id = "";
    using (var c1 = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
    {
        c1.MoveToFirst();
        System.String document_id = c1.GetString(0);
        doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    }
    string path = null;

    string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
    using (var cursor = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
    {
        if (cursor == null) return path;
        var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
        cursor.MoveToFirst();
        path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
    }
    return path;
}

public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
    base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation;

}
```

Comment: Es un error de compilacion o runtime?

Comment: hola error de compilación

Comment: Que tipo de dato es la variable uris?

Comment: Contiene la ubicación de la imagen, es para ubicar la imagen la cual deseo adjuntar al correo

Comment: Pero el tipo de dato de la variable es `String` o `Uri`?

Comment: Es uri (mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream, path)); y me marca el error en path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los constructores de [`Attachment`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.Mail.Attachment/) reciben String como parametro no Uri.
[`Uri.FromFile`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Net.Uri.FromFile/p/Java.IO.File/) returna un objeto [`Uri`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Net.Uri/) por lo que la variable `path` es de tipo `Uri`.

Intenta pasandole `filePath` al constructor de `Attachment`:

```
 var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(uris, "");
 var File = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
 var path = Uri.FromFile(File);
 mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraStream,  filePath));
```

Comment: hola no me funciono así  mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Intent.ExtraStream, path..AbsoluteUri)) me dice que no encuentra método de extensión y lo intente de esta manera   ;mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Intent.ExtraStream, path.ToString())); pero sale esta falla{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/android.intent.extra.STREAM".
File name: '/android.intent.extra.STREAM'
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, .... inSystem\Autorizacion.cs:151 } valoro tu ayuda soy nuevos estoy aprendiendo

Comment: Intenta pasandole la variable filePath a Attachment

Comment: me funciono de esta manera      mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(File .Path));
                    client.Send(mail);

Comment: Excelente, me alegra saber que te funciono.